# Why does Dynamics CRM 2013 plugin fire twice on owner change?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a simple plugin for a custom entity that is set to trigger on Update of my custom entity. It is registered in the Post Operation stage. I have noticed some strange behaviour when I make changes to the Owner field of the record in addition to other standard fields (e.g. text boxes, dates etc).

The plugin fires the first time and the only attributes that come across in the image are all the regular fields. The owner field does not come across.

The plugin then fires again, but the **Depth** property of the context is still only **one** (i.e. the plugin is not getting triggered by changes made in the plugin code). In this run of the plugin, the attribute that come across is only the **Owner** field.

My theory is that because the owner fields are 'special', the CRM is doing two different requests - one to change the regular fields, and then another request for changing the owner via an **AssignRequest**. However, I cannot find any 'official' documentation for this behaviour.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

I am running Dynamcs CRM 2013 UR2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Update` event fires during the `Assign` event. So if an assignment takes place your plug-in will execute. The same is true for `SetState` - if you activate/deactivate a record an `Update` event takes place. These items are not documented in the SDK.

A good practice is to use Attribute Filtering on your `Update` plugin so it only fires for the fields it is concerned about - this will, assuming it is isn't looking at the owner related fields, avoid it firing twice. If you have logic specific to record ownership you would put it in a plugin that is registered on the `Assign` event.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find official documentation about this, but I think Assign message is what you are looking for (if the entity is user-owned. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328576.aspx. I would strongly recommend that you specify Filtering Attributes if you are registering a plugin on Update message. You could also debug your plugin and inspect MessageName property of plugin context and see what message gets triggered. I hope this helps.